# Install cordova on mac osx el capitan

Tags: node.js, macos, cordova

Is there anyway to install cordova on OSX El Capitan?
I run into all kinds of issues here, not able to install it.
Like a warn for mini match being a lower version then 2.0.3
But the version was the latest. I tried downgrading.
I tried to ask a question https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11927 cordova, but they said that cordova was installed correctly.
So i went on to create a cordova project.

```
2016s-Mac-mini:~ Thuis$ sudo cordova create HalloApp
? May Cordova anonymously report usage statistics to improve the tool over time? Yes
(Y/n) Y
Thanks for opting into telemetry to help us improve cordova.
```

> Error: Cannot find module 'config-chain'

I found a work around for this:

```
npm install -g config-chain

npm install -g nopt

npm install -g umask

npm install -g nom-registry-client
```

Then tried again:
Now It's the error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'

I have not found a solution for this.
Is there anyone succeed at installing the latest version of cordova on OS X El Capitan?

Comment: Have you used the [official installer](https://nodejs.org/en/) to install Node? Are you using NVM? FWIW, warnings are just that: warnings. If they appear when installing a package created by someone else, you should assume that that person has accepted that their package is using an outdated/deprecated version of a particular module. Usually, there's no need to try and fix that yourself.

Comment: I started with the official installer, first choice was the stable version4.6.0. But then i got this warning. And tried to solve this with uninstalling and trying with other versions an work arounds suggested in different forums. Ever since then i got trouble and not able to get it working. Didn't use NVM yet, should I use NVM instead of npm?

Comment: You should probably stick to the official installer, and ignore warnings :)

Comment: Uninstalled Node and used the official installer. :Last login: Sat Oct  1 09:14:24 on console
2016s-Mac-mini:~ Thuis$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/{bin/{node,npm},lib/node_modules/npm,lib/node,share/man/*/node.*}
Password:
2016s-Mac-mini:~ Thuis$ sudo cordova create HalloApp
Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'
2016s-Mac-mini:~ Thuis$

Comment: Did you reinstall `cordova` with the newly installed version of Node/NPM?

Comment: No i didn't. Tried but getting further from home.
2016s-Mac-mini:~ Thuis$ sudo sudo npm uninstall -g cordova
unbuild cordova@6.3.1
2016s-Mac-mini:~ Thuis$ sudo install -g cordova
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 file2
       install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
       install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...
2016s-Mac-mini:~ Thuis$ sudo cordova create HalloApp
sudo: cordova: command not found

Comment: You missed `npm` before `install`. Also, if you previously removed everything in `/usr/local` related to Node, `cordova` should have also been removed already. What does `which npm` return?

Comment: Your right i forgot the npm. With npm I got the deprecated Warn mini match@2.0.10 then tried to create the new (my first)2016s-Mac-mini:~ Thuis$ sudo cordova create HalloApp
Creating a new cordova project.
sudo npm install -g iOS-sim went ok

Comment: You can safely ignore that warning.

Comment: sudo npm install -g iOS-sim: was installed properly
sudo npm install -g iOS-deploy: gave 
!!!! WARNING: You are on OS X 10.11 El Capitan, you may need to add the
!!!! WARNING:   `--unsafe-perm=true` flag when running `npm install`
!!!! WARNING:   or else it will fail.
!!!! WARNING: link:
!!!! WARNING:   https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy#os-x-1011-el-capitan

but seems to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got working so far, however with Warnings and not the latest versions.

OSX El capitan

Netbeans 8.1

Node.js and npm = V4.6.0 LTS

Xcode 8.0

Cordova 6.3.1

CLI:
sudo npm install -g cordova
Here i got warning about the version of mini match
sudo cordova create MyApp (this works)

cordova add platform :doesn't work in terminal but Netbeans can do this

Netbeans:
This works, and build was succeed, but there's some trouble with the iOS simulator and the whole system get stuck. I will open a new question for that.

Many thanks to Robert Klep 
Dank u wel